# Best way for saving infinit playlists (arrays) into db? (php mySql)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string, database

So  client gives me a string like `"1,23,23,abc,ggg,544,tf4,"` from user `12` . There can be infinit number of elements with no spaces just value,value,... structure. I have users table (with users uId(key), names etc). I have streams table with ( sId(key), externalID, etc values). User sends me externalId's. And I need to hawe externalId's in play list (not my sId's).  I need some way to store such array into my DB and be able to get it from DB.

I need to be able to do 2 things

1. return such string back to user
2. be able to get na array from it like `{1; 23; 23; abc; ggg; 544; tf4;}`

So what is best method  (best here means shourt(small amount of) code)

1. to store such data into db
2. to retrivew stored tata in bouth ways shown

Comment: First you need an infinitely large hard disk...

Comment: Learning to spell might be a good idea too..

Comment: I have it... ok let us say play list for no more than 10^10 items=)

Comment: Do you need to perform any sort of processing on the individual IDs?  If not then the simplest solution is to literally store the string as its received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, something like this should work:
`User: user_id
Value: user_id, value, id`
And according to your example `1,23,23,abc,ggg,544,tf4` from user `12`, you will have:

```
TABLE User  
user_id  
12
```

and

```
TABLE Value  
user_id | value | id  
12      | 1     | 0  
12      | 23    | 1  
12      | 23    | 2  
12      | ggg   | 4  
12      | abc   | 3  
...
```

id will be used for ordering list for each user, so if you want do retrieve it, just use this query: `SELECT value FROM VALUE WHERE user_id = 12 ORDER BY id`

Answer (score 1):

That's a classical one-to-many relationship. One user has many *external ids*:

```
User:         id, name
UserExternal: user_id, id # both fields as PK, id as CHAR
```

To fetch every external id connected to the user just execute the following query:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, ue.id AS external
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN user_external ue ON u.id = ue.user_id
```

Comment: it is related to storing my lists? how? ok I get an idea of classical one-to-many relationship but how it can halp in my situation?